# I get an error of Invalid character constant what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

```
 do {
  System.out.println("What is the Secret Word");
  secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water");
   if (secretWord != 'Water')
    secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water");
  }
```

I'm trying to make the user guess the word Water, if they don't then it would promt the user to guess 
     again. If they get it right, the program would echo the secret word Water

Answer (score 3):

1. On your 4th line down, you need to change 'Water' to "Water" because it is a String.
2. You are also missing the brackets for your if statement.
3. The != in the line `secretWord != "Water"` is not used to determine if a String does not equal another String. Instead use `.equals` to determine is a String equals another String.

Try this code instead:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
          System.out.println("What is the Secret Word");
          String secretWord = scanner.next();
          secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water"); // Delete this - line does nothing
           if (!secretWord.equals("Water")) {
            secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water");
          } 
        }while (!secretWord.equals("Quit"));
```

Also, you tagged Java and Javascript on this question. Those are two completely different languages. I'm assuming that you probably just meant Java.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I'm an undergraduate of Computer Science taking the introductory course.

Comment: Error: Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
Thats what I get

Comment: The code inside the 'do' will execute once. After is runs, it will look at the 'while' condition. If the while condition is true, the code inside the 'do' will execute again. If the while condition is false, the code will not execute again.

Look at this example on Oracles website - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: I added a while clause to complete your do while loop

Comment: I figured he had one but didn't include it in the question. However, that wasn't the case so thank you for adding it.

Comment: What is that lone `secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water");` meant to do? I'd suggest adding at least a comment for the OP to realize that it's kind of pointless that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you described – to prompt the user for a secret word repeatedly until they get it right.

It sets up a `Scanner` to capture input from the keyboard, then repeatedly loops – `while (true) { ... }` – printing something to the user, capturing the input, and checking if it matches "water". If it matches, it prints a messages and uses `break` to get out of the `while` loop.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("What is the Secret Word? ");
    String input = scanner.next();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("water")) {
        System.out.println("you guessed right!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: great - glad to help. remember to accept and/or vote up answers that helped. more detail in: _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 1):

Try the below Code.

```
do {
    System.out.println("What is the Secret Word");
    if (!secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Water"))
        System.out.println("Water is not Equal.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secretWord != 'Water'
```

u have to use " instead of '

Comment: how? use `"` instead of `'` (*you* did it with the other texts) single  quote is used for character, double quote for strings